# Can't Access VPS with LAMP installed from Internet

Tags: lamp, vps

I have a VPS with LAMP installed. I followed this link:

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-6
```

I tried to enter my IP in the web browser but nothing shows up.

Here are my ipTables

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot opt source     destination
ACCEPT      all -- anywhere     anywhere    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT      icmp -- anywhere    anywhere
ACCEPT      all -- anywhere     anywhere
ACCEPT      tcp -- anywhere     anywhere    state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT      all -- anywhere     anywhere    reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot opt source     desitnation
REJECT      all -- anywhere     anywhere    reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot opt source     desination
```

Here is ps aux | grep apache:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps aux | grep apache
apache  12500   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
apache  12501   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
apache  12502   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
apache  12503   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
apache  12504   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
apache  12505   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
apache  12506   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
apache  12507   0.0 0.1 232732  4724 ?  S   21:44   0:00    /usr/sbin/httpd
root    12508   0.0 0.0 103236  824 pts/0   S   22:55   0:00    grep apache
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your previous question, you can access the IP via SSH.
When you can't access the IP via HTTP, you either didn't start the webserver or you have a firewall.

List firewall rules with iptables

```
iptables -L
```

Verify webserver is running by

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

or install `lynx` and

```
lynx localhost
```

Comment: I updated the OP with the IP tables and the other replies from those commands.

Comment: Some people do 3 year education on setting up firewalls and servers. The best is you cancel the purchase, use a standard webhosting and setup yourself a virtual machine to get in touch with linux.

Comment: I am not worried about security or unauthorized access. I simply just need this to start up.

Comment: in most unix commands u can append `-h` to show help menu... Did you even google "how to delete iptable rules" ? Did you? If you want to hire someone to setup your server, make a goddamn offer

Comment: If anyone has any accurate and helpful advice please chime in.

Comment: I already gave you the most helpful advices: USE GOOGLE, USE `-h`. Using google, the first result for "delete firewall rules iptables" is this link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/deleting-firewall-rules/ Now say whats wrong with you?!

Comment: So I can go to any question on any forum or any question on Stackoverflow and if I say "use Google" then that is the most helpful answer. Sounds legit. Please stop posting on this question.